# In Glucose, how will you prove the presence of the following?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, carbohydrates

1. One carbonyl group
2. 5 hydroxyl groups
3. One primary alcholic group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1.  Reaction with $\ce{HCN}$, or with hydroxlyamine ($\ce{NH2OH}$)***

Glucose reacts with $\ce{HCN}$ to give a cyanohydrin, or with a schiffs base to give an oxime. This shows the presence of a carbonyl group.

***2. Reaction with acetic anhydride $\ce{(CH3CO)2O}$***

Glucose gives a penta ester with acetic anhydride, revealing that it has 5    hydroxyl groups.

***3. Reaction with Nitric acid***

On oxidation with Nitric acid ($\ce{HNO3}$),glucose as well as gluconic acid both yeild a dicarboxylic acid (saccharic acid). This indicates the presence of a primary alcoholic group in glucose.

Answer (score 1):

**To prove the presence of $\ce{-CHO}$ group:**

When glucose reacts with **hydroxylamine**, **oxime** is formed and ***cyanohydrins are formed*** on the addition of hydrogen cyanide to it. This reaction can confirm the presence of carbonyl group in glucose. And also on the reaction of glucose with a mild oxidising agent like bromine water, the glucose gets oxidised to carboxylic acid containing six carbon atoms. This indicates that the carbonyl group is present (as an aldehyde group).

**To prove the presence of $\ce{-OH}$ groups:**

The presence of $\ce{-OH}$ group is confirmed after the ***acetylation of glucose with acetic anhydride***, which gives glucose pentaacetate.

Hope this helps

Comment: The $\ce{OH}$ groups react with acetic anhydride to give acetates. Thus, I took the advantage to correct acetic acid to acetic anhydride. Please switch it back if you meant acetic acid.